# Oscillation frequencies in an ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, special-functions

Given the following ODE:
$$\ddot{x}(t)+\sin(\omega t)x(t)=0$$
its solution can be expressed in terms of the Mathieu functions. 
Plotting this solutions and assuming known the initial conditions it can be found a main oscillatory behaviour with another superimposed oscillation close to the maxima and minima of the solution. Now my question is: how can I find the frequencies of these oscillations knowing $\omega$? Or in other words, is there a formula linking the frequencies to $\omega$?

Comment: Isn't w = 2 * Pi * f?

Comment: @amzoti: yes it is.

Comment: When $\omega\rightarrow 0$, there is an adiabatic invariant.

Comment: @Jon: It's true, but I'm interested also in the case $\omega \to \infty$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is important to note that, if $\omega$ has physical dimensions, talking about it being large or small is meaningless. In order to treat this equation on a mathematical standpoint we need to introduce an "observation time" $\tau$ that gives the proper scale to time variable. In this case we have the equation
$$
  \ddot x+\frac{1}{\tau^2}\sin\left(\omega\tau\frac{t}{\tau}\right)x=0.
$$
Then, changing the time variable to $\theta=\frac{t}{\tau}$ and putting $\omega\tau=\lambda$, we are left with the equation
$$
  \ddot x+\sin(\lambda\theta)x=0.
$$
For this equation, [Floquet theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floquet%27s_theorem) applies  and a general form to the solution is given that is the product of two periodic functions.

It is worthwhile to note the two cases $\lambda\ll 1$ and $\lambda\gg 1$. The former produces an adiabatic invariant as is well known. This can be written in the form $(\dot x)^2+x^2$ (see [here](http://books.google.it/books?id=oyaFXgcFJ2cC&printsec=frontcover&hl=it&source=gbs_ge_summary_r&cad=0#v=onepage&q&f=false) for the theory). The other limit is intriguing as perturbation theory applies. This can be seen by the rescaling $w=\lambda\theta$. The equation takes the form
$$
  \lambda^2\ddot x+\sin(w)x=0
$$
and diving by $\lambda$ and setting $\epsilon=\frac{1}{\lambda^2}\ll 1$ one can do perturbation theory. The solution, assuming for the sake of simplicity $x(0)=a$ and $\dot x(0)=0$, has the form
$$
  x(w)=a+\epsilon a\sin(w)-\epsilon^2\left(\frac{a}{8}\cos(2w)+\frac{a}{8}+\frac{a}{4}w^2\right)+O(\epsilon^3)
$$
where another harmonic is seen to appear as a second order effect.